# What is .ini file and How to integrate it in android?

Tags: android, ini

I have integrated web service in my android application. I just want to add it's URL in ".ini" file. Before that I want to know that,

1. What is ".ini" file and what is the use of this file in Android ?
2. How to integrate it with my android project?
3. How to retrive data from ".ini" file to my android project?

Thanks.

Comment: Let me give you a great idea, Google it.

Comment: ini files in **Windows** are the analogue to SharedPreferences files on Android. But the former ones are plain text files (with a given formatting), while the latter ones are xml files.

Answer (score 0):

1. A .INI File contains configuration information for MS-Windows. Two.INI files, WIN.INI and SYSTEM.INI, are required by MS-Windows. In addition, many applications have their own.INI files. In Windows 95 and Windows NT,.INI files have been replaced by the Registry, though many applications still include.INI files for backward compatibility.
2. & 3. checkout: http://community.clickteam.com/threads/89153-INI-compatible-for-Android